# How can I go back to IE8 without major system changes on Windows 7 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I am a consultant and for that reason, I need to use VPN to do work for customers often.  However, after having upgraded to IE10 recently, I am unable to connect to their system. They only support IE6-IE8 so they cannot help me.

Is there any way to go back to IE8 which doesn't require major system changes?

Comment: Interesting, which VPN only works with IE6-IE8? Just so I know to avoid them. :)

Comment: @JNovack: It's a custom VPN for a local customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you did was go from IE8->IE10, according to documentation all you have to do is remove IE10 from the Programs And Freatures menu.

- Click the Start button, type Programs and Features in the search box,
  and then select View installed updates in the left pane.
- Under Uninstall an update, scroll down to the Microsoft Windows
  section.
- Right-click Internet Explorer 10, click Uninstall, and when prompted,
  click Yes.

  Click one of the following: Restart now (to finish the process of uninstalling Internet Explorer 10 and restore the previous version of Internet Explorer) or Restart later